# Is there any benefit to "cherry picking" node.js imports on the backend by important only one function instead of entire package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

Let's say in my file I only need `ObjectId` function from `mongoose` package.

Is there any benefit (CPU, memory, speed ...) to only importing said function instead of importing entire `mongoose` in my file?

My thoughts are:

1. Node.js imports the module once, so import costs should not increase and when using dot notation with require it first requires / imports entire package so there should be no difference in import costs again.
2. The variable that I set on import with cherry picked import is smaller and therefore requires less memory, but since mongoose is an object the variable only holds a reference to that object so it should be irrelevant whether I cherry pick or not. It's not like I am setting entire mongoose package into my variable. I am only setting a reference.

Importing all `mongoose`.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

function test() {
  const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
  // other code
}

module.exports = test;
```

Importing only `ObjectId`.

```
const ObjectId = require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId;

function test() {
  const id = ObjectId();
  // other code
}

module.exports = test;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right. There is no difference at all concerning performance and memory usage.

Some Notes:

- If you use a bundler to create a minified bundled file, only importing those things that you need might enable the bundler to do better treeshaking and reduce the filseize. That is only relevant for clientside code though.
- It makes your code slightly more readable if you only import those things that you actually need (e.g. you are trying to find the root cause of a weird database modification, for that you skim through all files that import mongoose, if you only import the ObjectId you can skip this file and continue to the relevant ones)